# repainting a JPanel and update the screen

Tags: java, swing

i 'm trying to " fade" a JPanel using a thread . Actually that not fading , but he turning the color white to black gradually by changing the rgb values ​​.

```
public class MostraPainel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        // Centraliza
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Painel painel = new Painel();
        jf.setContentPane(painel);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        new Thread(painel).start();

    }
}
```

So i want to repaint the panel by a interval i set, look the panel class

```
public class Painel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    // alt+s
    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    int cont = 0;

    public Painel() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (cont == 1)
            super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        // System.out.println(cont);
        g2.setColor(new Color(cont, cont, cont));
        int w = getWidth() - 1;
        int h = getHeight() - 1;
        int widthQ = w / 8;
        int heightQ = h / 8;
        int size = 0;
        int cont = 0;
        for (int j = heightQ; j < getHeight(); j += (2 * heightQ)) {

            for (int i = size; i < getWidth(); i += (2 * widthQ)) {
                if (cont == 0)
                    g2.fillRect(i + widthQ, 0, widthQ, heightQ);
                g2.fillRect(i + widthQ, j + heightQ, widthQ, heightQ);
                g2.fillRect(i, j, widthQ, heightQ);
            }
            cont++;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.cont++;
        for (cont = 0; cont < 255; cont++) {

            if (this.cont < 255) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                this.repaint();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

So the paintComponent() method draw a image on the panel, and the method run() repaint and sum 1 to  the cont variable. That actually work, but the screen doesn't update every time i execute the repaint(), so the fade have a low FPS. If i stay resizing the screen the fade works well, whats the problem?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java repaint() method doesn't always work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071321/java-repaint-method-doesnt-always-work)

Comment: You are blocking the super's paintComponent method from being called if cont does not == 1, and you should not be doing this since by doing this, you prevent the JPanel from doing its own housekeeping painting and erasing. Except with rare exception, the super's method should **always** be called within your override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by addin this line

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
```

Thanks for the help